# Auto Renewable subscription - in app purchase possible for normal apps or not

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am having my app on apple store,its a paid app ,in this app user getting data by api call, now i want to make app free and when user after downloading app,try to use app , than at that time i want to ask user for payment,is it possible i will use Auto renewal subscription of  in app purchase ,i want to do this bcoz i want to provide service to user only for 1 year after that user need to renew for service. I am having doubts bcoz somewhr i read Auto Renewable subscription only able to use for magazines and games app. Please help me in order to understand this concept.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN use auto-renewable subscriptions in non-magazine apps (for example a subscription in a game where every month you can get a new power/item or something).

Comment: Hi, but my app isnot game kind of or magazine kind of ,its a simple app in which user login and via api call get data related to his query.

Comment: I don't think Apple will complain about what you sell via the subscription. In the documentation they never mention it's to be used for magazines only, it's just the most common example: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html

Comment: i am not getting new item every month in my app ,sorry i am doing lots of cross questioning ,but its required.

Comment: its just like google search ,u r doing ur search in our db and getting response . and i want to give 1 year subscription for this service.

Comment: Still sounds valid to me. 1-year subscriptions are ok. :)

Comment: yes apple reject your app when you use auto-renewable.Same i did auto-renewable for my app. It is not an magazine or a game so apple rejected my app better you keep non-renewing subscription for this.

Comment: According to the documentation I believe your app provides a service like the example in page 6 here: https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf